# Win10 on-screen keyboard closes after using AltGr, even in hotkey?

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard, usability, dead-keys

The title says it all; when I enter an accented letter that requires an AltGr deadkey, the on-screen keyboard auto-closes. Very counterproductive (esp since it isn’t exactly giid at popping up immediately when needed)!!
Bug or feature?

Comment: Do you mean the physical key “AltGr”? The touch keyboard closes for *every* keypress. The touch keyboard does not appear to support dead keys. Use the on-screen keyboard instead.

Comment: Sorry, meant the on-screen keyboard indeed!

Comment: This is a known problem with the OSK. Only solution is to use a third-party product such as [Click-N-Type](https://cnt.lakefolks.com/), which has a good [review](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/click-n-type.htm-0).

Comment: Known by everyone except MS, I fear? I'll have to check this out. I haven't read through all reviews: does this also cause the target window to resize or scroll its contents when you open the OSK? (Not that this works so reliably with the system version...)

Comment: Again, are we talking about the *touch keyboard* or the *on-screen keyboard*. The former is a borderless window and can be brought up from the tray. The latter has a regular window border and is part of the accessibility tools.

Comment: I'm talking about the one used in tablet mode and for which the OS provides an optional icon in the taskbar. No border, so with this new hindsight I apparently meant the touch keyboard. Pardon me if the distinction isn't intuitive; both can be used with a touchscreen and both appear on the screen :-/

Comment: I understand it’s confusing, that’s why I was asking. Dead-keys and all other strangeness in my keyboard layout works perfectly fine with the accessibility on-screen keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

On-screen keyboard vs touchscreen keyboard regardless, this indeed turns out to be a known issue as commented by @harrymc. It's a bug that has been in Win10 since the 1803 release. There's a workaround: use AltGr-Ctrl instead (= hit Ctrl before hitting the key you wanted to hit). CluMSy ...